# How to specify function name on $http.get status?

Tags: angularjs

I have an angular function that looks like this.

```
function request($scope, $http) {    
  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
  .success(function (response) {
     $scope.names = response.records;
  });
}
```

I like to do replace the anonymous function with regular function just to get rid of the ugly indentation.  I am not sure what I am doing because I have not much success.   Basically, I like to to look something like this.

```
function request($scope, $http) {

  processGoodStatus = function (response) {
     $scope.names = response.records;
  }

  $http.get("http://www.w3schools.com/angular/customers.php")
  .success(processGoodStatus);
}
```

How would do something like that ?   Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you forget to use `var`

declare like this

```
var processGoodStatus = function (response) {
     $scope.names = response.records;
}
```

Comment: LOL.  so it is that simple huh.  I was so closed.   Thank you much.

Comment: you are welcome. this won't matter in normal mode but in strict mode you have to use var in order to declare.